# how to move a file after identifying it with ls | egrep , or "egrep" vs "find"

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression, mv

I need to move all images with a specific filename string to a specific directory.

This is an example filename

```
facility_92+SOURCE1+SOURCE1.0
```

After the 'facility_' there can be 1 to 5 digits.

The following will return a list of the files I wish to move:

```
ls | egrep "facility_([0-9]*)\+SOURCE[0-9]*"
```

However I get stuck when trying to move anything this returns. I have tried to use find to move matching files to the moved folder:

```
for f in 'find ./ | ls | egrep "facility_([0-9]*)\+SOURCE[0-9]*"'; do mv $f moved/; done
```

But am get a number of errors where mv parses the conditions as a string ...

I had another go with '-exec':

```
find ./ | ls | egrep "facility_([0-9]*)\+SOURCE[0-9]*" -exec mv moved
```

But receive similar errors ...

Advice appreciated. Am I wrong to try this approach at all? Should i just figure out how to do the same regex in 'find'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `find` you should *not* concatenate commands through piping.

It has a nice `-regex` flag to which you can pass your filename matching string:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex ".*facility_([0-9]*)\+SOURCE[0-9]*.*" -exec mv {} DIRECTORY \;
```

The final `\;` passes each one of the matching filenames to `mv` in place of the `{}`.

As you can see, you need to use `.*` at the beginning and at the end of the regular expression because `find` needs to mach on the *whole* path:

```
-regex pattern
       File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search. For  example, to  match  a  file named './fubar3', you can use the regular expression '.*bar.' or '.*b.*3', but not 'f.*r3'.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr Shunz, when I try that though I get this error ````find: missing argument to `-exec'````

Comment: @Jack sorry, looks like the `\+` doesn't work correctly with `mv`, please use `\;` instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MrShunz With GNU `mv`, you may use `-exec mv -t DIRECTORY {} +`. Note that when using `-exec ... +` the `{}` _must_ come immediately in front of the `+`.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705

Comment: Thanks, however while ````find . -regextype egrep -regex "vital_([0-9]*)\+SOURCE[0-9]*" -exec mv {} moved \;```` doesn't give an error, but unfortunately it doesn't move the file either.

Comment: @Jack does the `find` without `-exec` returns any file?

Comment: No, but ````ls | egrep "facility_([0-9]*)\+SOURCE[0-9]*" ```` does.

Comment: @Jack I just found out that `find` `-regex` must match on the whole path. You need a slightly different version of the regular expression. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's great, it works perfectly. Thanks for all your help @MrShunz.